# Unable to render a json object on panel application

Tags: panel, holoviews

**arihant@linux# pip list**
Package Version

---

bleach 6.0.0
bokeh 3.2.2
certifi 2023.7.22
charset-normalizer 3.3.0
colorcet 3.0.1
contourpy 1.1.1
holoviews 1.17.1
idna 3.4
Jinja2 3.1.2
linkify-it-py 2.0.2
Markdown 3.4.4
markdown-it-py 3.0.0
MarkupSafe 2.1.3
mdit-py-plugins 0.4.0
mdurl 0.1.2
numpy 1.26.0
packaging 23.2
pandas 2.1.1
panel 1.2.3
param 1.13.0
Pillow 10.0.1
pip 22.3.1
pyct 0.5.0
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz 2023.3.post1
pyviz_comms 3.0.0
PyYAML 6.0.1
requests 2.31.0
setuptools 65.5.0
six 1.16.0
tornado 6.3.3
tqdm 4.66.1
typing_extensions 4.8.0
tzdata 2023.3
uc-micro-py 1.0.2
urllib3 2.0.6
webencodings 0.5.1
xyzservices 2023.10.0

### [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 → 23.2.1

[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

### arihant@linux# python --version

Python 3.11.1

### **arihant@linux# lsb_release -a**

LSB Version: :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release: 7.9.2009
Codename: Core

code ref : [JSON — Panel v1.2.3](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/panes/JSON.html)
**arihant@linux# cat mypanel.py**

import json
import panel as pn

pn.extension()
json_obj = {
‘boolean’: False,
‘dict’: {‘a’: 1, ‘b’: 2, ‘c’: 3},
‘int’: 1,
‘float’: 3.1,
‘list’: [1, 2, 3],
‘null’: None,
‘string’: ‘A string’,
}

json = pn.pane.JSON(json_obj, name=‘JSON’)mypanel.py

pn.Column(json).show()

I am having the above python configuration on my linux machine, and I am just trying to run an sample panel application as mentioned above using python mypanel.py,
I am unable to see anything on the opened browser.

Launching server at [http://localhost:34491](http://localhost:34491/)
This tool has been deprecated, use ‘gio open’ instead. ( what’s this warning and how to overcome this ?
See ‘gio help open’ for more info.

After this the url is launched on browser, but that does not render anything. Please help me out !!!